# CodeIgniter controller not reading post data from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and i am trying to retrieve some data using AJAX POST, but the controller can't read the post data that i am sending to it.

this is  the ajax call:

```
$("#notifica").click(function(){
    var mydata = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>';

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>notification_navbar/notifications',
         contentType: 'text',
         dataType : 'text',
         cache:false,
         data: mydata,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log('dsada');
           $(".notifi").html(msg);
        }
    });   
});
```

and here is the controller:

```
class notification_navbar extends CI_Controller{

    function notifications(){
        $hello = 'hello world';
        var_dump($this->input->post());
        exit;
        echo $hello;
    }

}
```

the error that I am taking is that the var_dump is empty so I take false there!

The solution to the problem is that: 
i must change base_url to site_url

Comment: This is other with forms! this one is with ajax call! it's deferent the one from the other!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#notifica").click(function(){
    var mydata = {username:'<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>'};

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>notification_navbar/notifications',
         contentType: 'text',
         dataType : 'text',
         cache:false,
         data: mydata,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log('dsada');
           $(".notifi").html(msg);
        }
    });   
});
```

---

```
class notification_navbar extends CI_Controller{

    function notifications(){
        $hello = 'hello world';
        var_dump($this->input->post());
        exit;
        echo $hello;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the serialize method before sending the data.

[form serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then if you see in your Firebug console you will see error in your js because you are not making mydata string correct. Replace

```
var mydata = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>';
```

with

```
 var mydata = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>";
```